# How do I add a touch event to a subview of UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch

I'm trying to build by very first app so excuse my ignorance. I love the sample code that Apple put together here called ViewTransitions:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

I want the transition to occur after a user taps the screen once instead of the button like the code does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the inherited class of your xib to be UIControl.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the touch events in your view.